# How can I check in my test that the method returns a time.ticker with the specified duration?

Tags: go

How can I test for the correct return value in this method?

```
func CreateTicker(dur time.Duration) *time.Ticker {
    return time.NewTicker(dur * time.Second)
}
```

```
func TestCreateTicker(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        dur time.Duration
    }
    var (
        ticker = time.NewTicker(12)
    )

    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want *time.Ticker
    }{
        {
            name: "test",
            args: args{dur: 12},
            want: ticker,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := CreateTicker(tt.args.dur); !reflect.DeepEqual(got, tt.want) {
                t.Errorf("CreateTicker() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

At the moment when I run the test I get the error message that the objects are not identical.

```
--- FAIL: TestCreateTicker (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestCreateTicker/test. (0.00s)
      CreateTicker() = &{0xc000062360 {824633909248 32883400129906 12000000000 0x471bc0 0xc000062360 0 0 1}}, want &{0xc0000622a0 {824633909248 32871400127913 12 0x471bc0 0xc0000622a0 0 0 1}}
FAIL
...
```

Comment: Some things are just wrong to test.

Comment: A function that just makes a single call to a stdlib function passing in its own argument seems in itself not very valuable, let alone a unit test for it.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's not difficult to look at unexported `r.when` field using reflection. If only for exercise. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to test this, you would have to actually measure how long it takes the timer to emit two ticks, and check whether the delta is within an acceptable range. That's a lot of effort for a test that is not very useful, and your test-to-code ratio is already showing quite a poor return on investment, with 25 lines of test covering a 1 line function.

The better solution is to not test this. It's a single line that calls out to a standard library function, which you can assume is well tested.

Comment: That`s a really good point.

Comment: Surprise: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/time/tick_test.go

Comment: Do you know how I can mock the call to newsTicker? The method has a few more lines of code that I left out.

Comment: If you really want to mock it, you can use `var CreateTicker = func(...) { ... }` at global scope, and then in your test, simply run `CreateTicker = func(...) { mock implementation }`. Keep in mind that if you do this in your tests, anything else can also do this at runtime.

Comment: ok that means I should always use dependency injection to get testable methods.

Comment: Only if those methods have dependencies you want to mock out for testing. Lots of methods are testable without dependency injection.